# How return substring of count for override for found december?

Tags: excel-formula, substring, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that will always return varying row contents. So I need to search each row to find the january, february, march, april, may, june, july, etc content and extract the counts from that in the cell with substring.  I'm not certain how to do this since the location in the row will always vary.  Any ideas? I was thinking vlookup or index or match, or mid/search, but I'm not sure.

Example spreadsheet content, notice some rows have the overallCount and some have overrideCount, and a string like "overallCount 2022/12 35" is the complete cell value, where 2022 is the year, and 12 is the month:

```
result1                     result2                     result3                  result4        
overallCount 2023/01 11     overallCount 2022/12 35     overallCount  2022/01 12 overrideCount 2022/08 5
overallCount 2023/02 1      overallCount 2022/11 34     overrideCount 2022/02 9  overrideCount 2022/01 5
------                      (3 rows)                    OverrideYearOrders       overrideCount 2022/10 2               overallCount 2023/01 6
```

And the rows can have varying column numbers as well if there are more or less orders for each device.

I want to add a formula in result8 column or so, and search to the left of each row, and pull out the counts in columns for Jan, Feb, March, April, May, etc.  I was thinking of something like this:

=VLOOKUP("overrideCount 2022/12",H6:AC8517,1,FALSE)

but it's not returning the count.  It's returning #N/A

example per-row output on the right:

```
Overall                                                                       Override
Jan2022  Feb  March  April May  June  July  Aug  Sept Oct  Nov  Dec Jan2023   Jan2022 Feb  Mar ...
                                                                35  11        5
```

As you can see, not every month has a count that would be found in the row.
How would I pull those monthly counts for overall and override out to the right in each row?

Update*

This is the generated table per comment below:

| result1 | result2 | result3 | result4 | result5 | Output to right here Overall Jan2022 | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Override Jan2023 | Override Jan2022 | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| overallCount 2023/01 11 | overallCount 2022/12 35 | overallCount 2022/01 12 | overrideCount 2022/01 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 35 | 11 | 5 |  |
| overallCount 2023/02 1 | overallCount 2022/11 34 | overrideCount 2022/02 9 | overrideCount 2022/01 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 34 |  |  | 5 | 9 |
| ------ | (3 rows) | OverrideYearOrders | overrideCount 2022/10 2 | overallCount 2023/01 6 | 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Example output is shown to right in generated table above, and also example **per-row output** is given in this before this added update already.

Comment: It may be helpful to post your data as markdown tables https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# right now it's hard to tell where a cell starts/ends. Also please provide an example of the result you'd like to get. Maybe you could use only a few samples to show your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FORMULA:**

This formula will get you to where you want pending a couple changes.

1. Rename the column headers to represent the date you want to calculate for (1/1/2022, 2/1/2022, ...).
2. This formula requires every cell value to "search" to be of "overallCount yyyy/mm" or "overrideCount yyyy/mm"
   format

Drag and drop the formula for as far as you need it (row and columns).

First formula, totaling **overallCount** (F2:s2)

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(F$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($A2:$E2,LEN($A2:$E2)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(F$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)+20)),0)))>0,SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(F$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($A2:$E2,LEN($A2:$E2)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(F$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)+20)),0))),"")
```

Second formula, totalling **overrideCount** (R2:AG2)

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overrideCount "&TEXT(T$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($A2:$E2,LEN($A2:$E2)-(FIND("overrideCount "&TEXT(T$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)+21)),0)))>0,SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overrideCount "&TEXT(T$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($A2:$E2,LEN($A2:$E2)-(FIND("overrideCount "&TEXT(T$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)+21)),0))),"")
```

**EXPLANATION:**

- The formula is using the `SUMPRODUCT` function which multiplies the corresponding elements of the arrays and returns the sum of products.
- The formula uses the `SEARCH` function to look for the occurrence
  of the string in the cells using the format
  "yyyy/mm", in the cells of the range A2:E2 and returns **TRUE** if
  found, otherwise returns **FALSE**.
- The formula uses the `IFERROR` function to check for errors and returns
  0 if error is found.
- The formula uses the `RIGHT` function and is used to extract the rightmost
  part of the cell, starting from the position of the found string -20/-21 (calculation that takes advantage of the date in the column header plus its position in order to autofill). In short, it totals the number after the date.

**EXAMPLE:**

[image: Example]

The following formula is the root formula that is just wrapped in an `IF` `THEN` statement to show empty cells instead of 0's. This formula is written assuming Cells A1:E1 are the 'results' headers, and starting at Cell F1 is the date start of your dates. (Jan22-Feb23 of each category)

```
SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(F$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($A2:$E2,LEN($A2:$E2)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(F$1,"yyyy/mm"),$A2:$E2)+20)),0)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that's great.  What about the part where I have some cells that have override 2022/01 35, and some are overall 2022/01 10.  So they are prepended with override or overall.   There's 2 different categories of the counts I need to extract per Month.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to format my column header dates to be 01/2022, and it's displaying as J-22, and the cell shows it as 1/1/2022, even though I added it in as 1/2022. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't notice there were two different categories, I don't quite understand the table you posted as the way I am understanding it, there are values missing, and values that should not be there. For example your first row "Override Jan2023" should have the `11` in the Overall column instead right? And the second row should have a "Overall Feb2022" value of `1` right?

Comment: The formatting won't effect the formula so you should be good as long as the value is 1/1/2022 etc.. You can change it if it bothers you by highlighting those cells, right clicking, and choosing Format Cells. Lastly, you will have columns from Jan-2022 to Feb-2023 for BOTH categories right?

Comment: overallCount 2023/01 11 should have an 11 in Jan/2023 column.  So the Override Jan2023 column is mis-labeled and should be overall Jan 2023.  sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, I would have result columns for Jan-22 to Feb-2023 for Both categories (overall and override).

Comment: Would a typical formula be like this? =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH(TEXT(AD$5,"overrideCount yyyy/mm"),$A6:$AA6)>0,FALSE)*IFERROR(RIGHT($A6:$AA6,LEN($A6:$AA6)-(FIND(TEXT(AD$5,"overrideCount yyyy/mm"),$A6:$AA6)+7)),0))

Comment: My table header starts at row 5, and formula results are under that starting on column AD. Data ends in the table around column AA

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the formula to pull out the override and overall counts from each cell into the right column/row.

Comment: Check out the updated post, this isn't the most elegant but is what you are looking for I believe. Column F:S indicates Jan22-Feb23 overallCounts, and Columns T:AG indicates Jan22-Feb23 overrideCounts.

Comment: If the table header (result1) starts at A5 then we will have to adjust the cell references depending on where all the information falls. I will post the simplified version so you can digest it easier and make changes as necessary.

Comment: When I use the same spreadsheet dim as you it returns the correct counts.  But when I try to edit it for my spreadsheet (in this case 12/2022 heading is in AO5, it gives #VALUE for December 2022. =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($J6:$AA6,LEN($J6:$AA6)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)+20)),0)))>0,SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($AA6:$AD6,LEN($J6:$AA6)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)+20)),0))),"")

Comment: So AO5 is 12/2022 (Meaning 1/2022 falls in cell AD5)... Then your data you are querying begins in cell J6 and runs through AA6 (meaning cell J5 is "result1")? If so then the formula is fine EXCEPT you have a random `$AA6:$AD6` in there towards the end. Change that to `$J6:$AA6`. The only two cell references you should see are `AO$5` and `$J6:$AA6`.

Comment: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($J6:$AA6,LEN($J6:$AA6)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)+20)),0)))>0,SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(SEARCH("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)>0,FALSE)*SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(RIGHT($J6:$AA6,LEN($J6:$AA6)-(FIND("overallCount "&TEXT(AO$5,"yyyy/mm"),$J6:$AA6)+20)),0))),"")`